# VBA - Importing a .txt file from a network drive

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have no trouble when using the following code (just a snippet to show file path) to import a .txt file from my desktop:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\users\username\desktop\filename.txt", _
    Destination:=Range("Sheet1!$B$1"))
```

However, I can't manage to import a .txt file from a network drive with the following code:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;\\path.com\path\path\path\path\path\path\filename.txt", _
    Destination:=Range("Sheet1!$B$1"))
```

In case of any confusion, I'm using "path" just for privacy in the above code. Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to read it from an actual website? or just a normal UNC name?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: @braX I don't believe it's from an actual website. However, when I navigate to the .txt file using File Explorer, ".com" is in the path... I think it just calls out the server... Difficult for me to answer, as I'm a mechanical guy not a software/IT guy. But I'm learning!

Comment: @MatSnow I just get the standard "cannot find filepath" error.

Comment: I have the drive mapped as an X: drive. So locally, X:path\path\path\filename.txt works. But I want to be able to run the macro from other computers, where the drive may or may not be mapped. I hope this info helps...

Comment: It sounds like a UNC path. Try putting the file in the root of your path (i.e. `\\path.com\`) and then attempt to access it. If you can, it would suggest that your path isn't correct

Comment: is the path name really long?